# Has there ever been a film treatment - tv or movie - of Man in the High Castle?

Tags: movie, tv, alternate-history, the-man-in-the-high-castle

There's been quite a number of film treatment of SF novels by Phillip K Dick and they have all, at least to my impression, been wildly successful from *Blade-Runner* based on his *Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep* to *Total Recall* based upon *We Can Remember It For You Wholesale*.

But he didn't also write SF, he also wrote Alt-History. In *Man In The High Castle* is about an alternative history where Hitler happened to win WWII. Laughable of course now - but still thought-provoking.

It seems ideal for a film treatment. Has one ever been mooted? Or done? Whether on TV or the Big Screen.

Comment: FWIW the answer is in the tag description...

Comment: I'd argue as a sci fi fan that... most film treatments of PKD's novels had nothing to do with the actual novels

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Film is a creative discipline. This often means they take liberties wirh a story. Why bother reading the same book and watch the same story? Only a pedant who want to watch fifty reruns of the same film might want to do that ...

Comment: I'm puzzled why this question was asked here, as it comes up straight away if you even type the title into a search engine. I don't think SE is adding value to a basic usage of a search engine here.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: A thought for next time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it could easily be answered by Google.

Comment: @DanielRoseman "general reference" isn't a close reason any more. It's a *bad* question, but not an off-topic one.

Answer (score 9):

[Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_in_the_High_Castle_(TV_series)) - it was a TV adaptation that ran for four seasons on Amazon's Prime Video streaming service from 2015-2019